# How to create a custom button in a DetailsView in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, detailsview

I am a newbie in ASP.NET. I just want to ask if it is possible to create a button or hyperlink in a DetailsView. I know that there are Edit, Delete, etc. in a DetailsView, but I want to create another button or hyperlink for my own function.

Actual Scenario:
I have a DetailsView connected in a temporary sql server table via ObjectDataSource. What I need to do is to check/view each data in that table through the DetailsView and if I think the data is correct, I must click a certain button/hyperlink to transfer that data (row) to another table in that DB.

Please help me...

Answer (score 3):

Select the tiny arrow on top of the details view and select Edit Fields

Double click the ButtonField to add a button...

Change the settings to suit your needs (ButtonType and Text) and most importantly CommandName which might be "Check" for your scenario

And for the event use the ItemCommand event

```
 void MyDetailView_ItemCommand(Object sender, DetailsViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        // Use the CommandName property to determine which button
        // was clicked. 
        if (e.CommandName == "Check")
        {

           //Do Anything you like
        }

    }
```

Comment: You might want to check this link as well
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.itemcommand.aspx